# Qt Creator Giving errors after "Removing" a library

Tags: c++, qt

I downloaded a library and tried it. It gave me a lot of errors and after some research, I found that it was really old. I deleted the link in .pro file and removed the folder from project folder. However, when I try to debug, It gives me errors in main.cpp. My main.cpp has 15 lines and it gives me errors up to line 57. It says:

```
Undefined reference to 'every function here'
```

I think its the main.cpp from the lib but I deleted it... The undefined functions were used in that .cpp file... How come do I still have errors from it after deleeting the lib ? 
Thanks

Comment: Please try to give all relevant information. Is it a build, link or runtime error message. Which functions are undefined. What is your code. Mentioning line numbers without code has no meaning. Try to rebuild your project completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running qmake and then build the project. Any change in the .pro file has to be followed by running qmake. Running qmake will update the make files used to build the project.

Easiest way to run qmake is right click on project and select "Run qmake".

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Yup, running QMake again worked... Thanks! Only tried rebuilding but I guess qmake was the problem.